# Spring Data + Neo4j

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, spring-data

I try to run the following "Hello world" [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/tree/master/spring-data-neo4j-examples/hello-worlds) using Spring Data and Neo4j.

I use Maven and execute `mvn clean test`.

Build was successful by I not have an idea how to run the application. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Please explain why -1. Any other idea how to present the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Hello world' example you mentioned doesn't seem to have any program entry point - can not be run like a command line program. This is common for example programs. They often show how to create basic classes and show how to use them through test. So creating a application itself is your task.

You might want to create your own using Spring Boot which is described in this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/

Basicly you define a class as a SpringBootApplication and then program can start there. After that usage of Spring Neo4J is same as in featured tests.